# Cannot find xfeatures2d.hpp in opencv

Tags: opencv

I have followed the steps to install opencv_contrib modules with cmake and visual studio multiple times but VS still does not detect the xfeatures2d.hpp file. Please help.

Comment: Can you write which steps did you made ?

Comment: this link http://answers.opencv.org/question/57397/cant-find-xfeatures2dhpp/  may help.

Comment: I followed the steps again and it worked this time but I can't find the nonfree library. I want to use the SURF feature.